# Changed button control template and now mouseover wont work

Tags: c#, wpf

My button looks like this:

```
<Button ToolTip="Pending" Height="33" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,5,379,0" Name="radButton2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="64" Background="#FF515151" BorderBrush="#FF515151" FontSize="14" Foreground="#FF5F5C5C" FontFamily="Mangal" Command="{Binding SetToPendingCommand}" IsEnabled="{Binding IsSetToPendingButtonEnabled}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
            <Button.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate>
                                <Border BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="1.5" CornerRadius="0">
                                    <TextBlock Text="Pending" Foreground="White" TextAlignment="Center" FontSize="13" Margin="0,4, 0, 0" />
                                </Border>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Button.Style>
        </Button>
```

How do I get the mouseover to work correctly. I have tried not using a style and setting the  template directly but that didnt't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it is to move `Triggers` into `ControlTemplate`, give `Border` some name, for example `x:Name="PART_Border"`, and then in the `Setter` you can specify `TargetName="PART_Border"`:

```
<Button ...>
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Border BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="1.5" CornerRadius="0" x:Name="PART_Border">
                            <TextBlock Text="Pending" Foreground="White" TextAlignment="Center" FontSize="13" Margin="0,4, 0, 0" />
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" TargetName="PART_Border"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>                
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Move the trigger to ControlTemplate instead:

```
<ControlTemplate>
    <Border BorderThickness="1.5" CornerRadius="0">
        <TextBlock x:Name="txtBlock" Text="Pending" Foreground="White"
                   TextAlignment="Center" FontSize="13" Margin="0,4,0,0" />
     </Border>
     <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
           <Setter TargetName="txtBlock" Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
        </Trigger>
     </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: i tried this way and It didnt seem to work for me...maybe specifying the target name like @dkozl mentioned would work here...will test it out

Comment: In posted answer i have given the target name. Have you used the template i provided in the answer?

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is add a template binding to the background property of the Border:

```
<Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="1.5" CornerRadius="0">
   <TextBlock Text="Pending" Foreground="White" TextAlignment="Center" FontSize="13" Margin="0,4, 0, 0" />
</Border>
```

The important part is:

Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"

As it stands in the question the trigger is changing the template Background property, but that property is not being used within the control template.